# Differential Entropy of Gaussian Process

Tags: entropy, gaussian-process, information-theory

I have $N$ datapoints that have $d$ features in a GP and their covariance matrix $K$ and I want to calculate the differential entropy of that GP.

Is this formula right?

$E(I)= \frac{1}{2} \log((2πe)^d \det(K))$

Moreover, given $L$ the cholesky decomposition of $K$ is there a faster way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can see the formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Properties_of_differential_entropy). At least, I am assuming that you have performed the "kernel trick" and are doing the analysis in feature space. K would have $d$ dimensions.

There is a good discussion of the best way to calculate the determinant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886280/how-to-find-determinant-of-large-matrix.).

My answer would be that if you have to ask that question, you need to use one of the well established linear algebra code libraries - say Eigen or Armadillo.

Comment: Thank you! then the $2πe$ is powered in the number of datapoints and not the number of features? Finally do you take the absolute value of the determinant?

Comment: If the determinant is negative then $K$ cannot be a covariance matrix, so no absolute value is needed or even recommended.

Comment: The exponent is powered by the dimension of K. If K is the dxd covariance matrix of the feature space, then d is the exponent you need.